# EINVAL when connect to a unix domain socket in K8s container

Tags: python, c, kubernetes, unix-socket

I want to connect to a container create by K8s using unix domain socket, here is my logic in container:

```
def main():
    file_sock = tornado.netutil.bind_unix_socket("/test/f.sock")
    client, address = file_sock.accept()
    ...
```

this container will start by K8s with configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: base
        image: <image repo>
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /test/
          name: socket-volume
      volumes:
      - name: socket-volume
        emptyDir:
          sizeLimit: 500Mi
```

Now I want to connect to this `f.sock` from outside. I need to get the path from `config.json` of that container.

To do that, I can use `runc list` to get the bundle, and `config.json` in the bundle has a property named `mounts`. The volume I use will map to a path inside `mounts` like:

```
"mounts": [
    {
        "destination": "/test/",
        "type": "bind",
        "source": "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/854cad13-3cde-40f1-a058-dc069a850226/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/socket-volume",
         "options": [
             "rw",
             "rbind",
             "rprivate",
             "bind"
         ]
    },
]
```

After getting the path of `f.sock`, I can use C code to connect to it:

```
int main() {
    struct sockaddr_un_longer {
        sa_family_t sun_family;
        char sun_path[512];
    };

    int s, len, ret;
    struct sockaddr_un_longer remote = { .sun_family = AF_UNIX };

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("error when open socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(remote.sun_path, sockPath);
    printf("socket path: %s\n", remote.sun_path);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    printf("remote: %s\n", (char *)&remote);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
        printf("errno is: %d\n", errno);
        printf("error when connect socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is the error I got:

```
remote:
errno is: 22
error when connect socket
```

As far as I am concerned, `22` means invalid argument. And if I run python code directly in local, connect error won't happen.

Anyone who can help me is awesome!

Comment: Why are you defining your own `sockaddr_un_longer` type?

Comment: @pmacfarlane As you can see, the path comes from K8s is too long to feed into original `sockaddr_un` type. So I have to redefine it and extend the length of `sun_path` to 512(original length is 108)

Comment: I don't think that's a valid thing to do. `connect()` invokes a system call to the kernel, which checks that the length you pass it is what it expects (which is 108 bytes for the path), and fails if it is not.

Comment: @pmacfarlane That's maybe the reason, and I have no idea how kernel implement it. But I am wonder whether I have a way to achieve longer path. (Because I need it here)

Comment: Linux has an [abstract namespace](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/SocketAbstractNamespace?showcomments) for unix domain sockets, which you might be able to use. The socket just has a name, with no path required. See the man page for [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html). I've never tried this with K8 though, so I can't say for sure it would work.